# The prop `children` is marked as required in `Button`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to convert an older Material UI implementation. The Docs are bit laggy.

I get this error. The docs say

> Name          Type    Default Description
>
> children *    node        The content of the
>   button.

What does this mean and what do I have to put in my code?

```
<Button
  variant="raised"
  color="primary"
  className={classes.Button}
  label={this.state.buttonLabel}
  onClick={this.handleClick}
>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"children" are what is between the tags:

```
<Button>we are the children</Button>
```

Because you don't pass anything - it's *undefined*. To fix error just add something that React can render, like string:

```
<Button
  variant="raised"
  color="primary"
  className={classes.Button}
  label={this.state.buttonLabel}
  onClick={this.handleClick}
>
  My Button
</Button>;
```

Comment: Thanks. That was dumb of me but this is correct. The docs are bit unclear for a noob but at least if you know what you are doing it's easy to figure it out.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like they removed the `label` property and moved it to the `children` prop.

So you have to put it between the tags e.g.

```
<Button> here comes the label </Button>
```

You can always check the demos for the Components. See [here](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/buttons/)